# How to display on the same line label and div in the following context

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to display on the same line label and div in the context of bootstrap.
I did try the following code but it does not work:

```
.control-group​ {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/1028/

P.S.:
I would like just to change the css rule not the dom

Answer (score 3):

They have another one option. Use this code

```
.control-label {
float:left;
}
```

**Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/1031/)**

Answer (score 2):

Hi now add `display inline-block` in your `.controls` div

as like this

```
.control-group , .controls{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/hU6Kz/1029/)***

Answer (score 1):

`.control-group` is parent div and you have child `div.controls` which need to set `inline-block` to show in one single line.

Try this CSS,

```
.controls {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/hU6Kz/1030/